# SQL replace - find word and replace it

Tags: sql-server

i have one task.
I have a table which contain some columns. One column is a TEXT - string, which contain some sentences or some html code with neccesary text. I need find a text which contain some word f.e. 'TEAM' and replace it to 'AMOUNT'.

I tried something but it change all text in column only to AMOUNT, My goal is 'this is a TEAM' replace to 'this is a AMOUNT'. (The word TEAM i have in 250 documents and i need change only this one word in all documents in TEXT column)

```
Update TABLE
SET Text = replace('TEAM', 'TEAM', 'AMOUNT')
Where text like '%TEAM%'
```

Comment: 1st parameter of REPLACE function must be the string where the replacement must be performed. In your case this is initial value of `text` column - but you type `'TEAM'` literal instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need  the text column in replace

```
Update TABLE
SET Text = replace(text, 'TEAM', 'AMOUNT')
Where text like '%TEAM%'
```

seems you are not using mysql but sql.serve and you have ntext
so you could try using a cast

```
Update TABLE
SET Text = replace(cast text  as nvarchar(4000), 'TEAM', 'AMOUNT')
Where text like '%TEAM%'
```

Comment: hmm Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'TEAM'.

Comment: Update Table
SET Text = replace(Text, 'TEAM', 'AMMOUNT')
Where text like concat('%',TEAM,'%')
DocumentID VersionID LanguageID Text            Change TextShort

-222                   1                    12        <p>test TEAM</p>      NULL            NULL

Comment: answer updated  missing quite around team .. and also concat is not useful in this case

Comment: Is there any differents when data type of column TEXT ntext? in documentaiton its string, but when I use your query I get Argument data type ntext is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.

Comment: MSSQL, Microsoft SQL Server, my fault sorry

Comment: why you tagged  mysql ??? .. anyway answer  updated . with a suggestion .. and you should not use ntext  .